# How to fill Pandas dataframe column with numpy array in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop generating three values, age(data type int64),dayofMonth(data type numpy.ndarray) and Gender(data type str). I would like to store these three values of each iteration in a pandas data frame with columns as age,Day & Gender.Can you suggest how to do that?I'm using python 3.X
I tried this code inside for loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Age","Day", "Gender"])
for i in range(100):
      df.loc[i]=[age,day,gender]
```

I can't able to share sample data but can give one example,

```
age=38,day=array([[1],
       [3],
       [5],
       ..., 
       [25],
       [26],
       [30]], dtype=int64) and Gender='M'
```

But I'm getting error message as `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Comment: Can you show how that loop works? Do you mean an iterable of a 3-tuple?

Comment: Can you give sample data, expected output, and some code that you tried, but did not work?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, 
I have updated my post with code I used & error message I got